# How to securely pass variables to PHP script from Swift application, or make this code more secure

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I am using NSURL to call a PHP script that interacts with with a MySQL database. I am passing the variables through the URL, which can be intercepted and hacked. Is there any way to pass form data with Swift, or securely pass variables to a URL using a similar structure that I have now? I have completed the application only to realize this vulnerability. If there is no way to alter this code, I guess I will have to rewrite a bunch... 
Here is the structure code I have:

```
    let username = "bob" 
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/phpscript.php?username=\(username)")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            if error != nil {
                 print("Error: \(error)")
            } 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

As you can see, it would be simple to gather the username just by seeing the URL. Do you know of a way to pass variables other than through the URL, without having to rewrite all of this code?
Thank you very much

Comment: Use https instead of http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass username through post by adding between `..."POST"` and `let task...` this code:

```
let postString = "username=\(username)"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

end result:

```
let username = "bob" 
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/phpscript.php")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "username=\(username)"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if error != nil {
             print("Error: \(error)")
        } 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Thank your for the help!

Comment: Using POST doesn't make it secure at all. The data can still be easily viewed. Think of POST merely as a form of obfuscation, not actual security. You need to use https instead of http.

Comment: But the OP said that they wanted to "pass variables other than through the URL" Also, https requires certificates, and a bunch of pain with a CA, which is not necessary in order to do what they said they wanted.

Comment: since OP is obviously worried about the data being intercepted and his service compromised, just using a POST request will add no additional security whatsoever. Everything besides using SSL or other encryption of the sent data won't do.

Comment: @user3117152 Read the start of the question. The OP is asking how to securely pass values to a URL. Using POST provides no security. I hope the OP comes back and sees these comments. I'm afraid they saw your answer, excepted it, and now think their code is secure. Yet another data breach waiting to happen.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Do you know of a simple way to secure this flaw? Would encrypting the URL be the best bet, or using https or SSL? If I use https or SSL can I still use the code I have that sends requests with the NSURL structure I already have? Thank you

Comment: Would JSON be a more secure alternative?

Comment: JSON would not add security, but adding asymmetric key encryption or SSL would. Https is http with SSL. In order to have asymmetric encryption you could send the data the same way, and you would just have to encrypt the data before sending it with this method.